# SQL Server lat;lng varchar split procedure to use as Lat and Lng for speed Searching

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, geolocation

Can someone help me using a stored procedure or function to passing my stored `varchar` lat;lng in table to individuals fields as float as Lat and Lng to use in radius search.

```
lanlng in Table
33.0000;15.222222
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you just trying to split the string? If so:

```
declare @LatLng varchar(100)
set @LatLng = '33.0000;15.222222'

declare @Lat float
declare @Lng float

select @Lat = CAST(LEFT(@LatLng, charindex(';',@LatLng)-1) as float)
select @Lng = CAST(SUBSTRING(@LatLng, charindex(';',@LatLng)+1, LEN(@LatLng)-charindex(';',@LatLng)) as float)

select @Lat as Latitude, @Lng as Longitude
```

Comment: Joe, this is correct for inputs values but what about using the column in a Where clause (GeoLatLng is the table column) like WHERE (@R*2*ATN2(SQRT((SIN((RADIANS(CAST(LEFT(GeoLatLng, charindex(';',GeoLatLng)-1) as float) - @lat2Compare)) / 2) no better way?

Comment: You've probably got a couple of options here. Add computed columns to your table based on the string split functions. Write user defined functions to encapsulate the string split and use those functions in your where clause.