# Need to move SQL Server 2005 Table storing Lat;Lng as varchar to Spatial?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, geospatial, spatial-data

I have read some articles about using spatial optimized tables. Actually I use stored latitude and longitude as `varchar` comma-separated (lat;lng).

Could you suggest the best way to perform this change and enumerate the advantages. It's really necessary for a large project or only move to SQL Server 2008?

thanks.

Comment: I already enumerated some options (computed columns, user-defined functions) for your situation when you asked the question here: [MSSQL lat;lng varchar split procedure to use as Lat and Lng for speed Searching](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3873619/mssql-latlng-varchar-split-procedure-to-use-as-lat-and-lng-for-speed-searching/3873892#3873892).

Comment: The advantages gained by storing your lat/long values will depend on how you USE these values.  Can you please elaborate on that?

Comment: These values are used in Haversine distance to calcule geopoints. Joe could you sugest the best way for a large database that preserve performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd add two new [persisted computed colunns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186241.aspx) to your table as illustrated in the demo below.

```
create table Demo (
    LatLng varchar(100),
    Lat as CAST(LEFT(LatLng, charindex(';',LatLng)-1) as float) PERSISTED,
    Lng as CAST(SUBSTRING(LatLng, charindex(';',LatLng)+1, LEN(LatLng)-charindex(';',LatLng)) as float) PERSISTED
)

insert into Demo
    (LatLng)
    values
    ('33.0000;15.222222')

select *
    from Demo

drop table Demo
```

Comment: Great joe, thks. This table is sqlserver2005 not optimized for geometry searching. Could you explain about move this solution to optimized geometry http://mssqlspatial.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Getting%20Started&referringTitle=Tutorials

Comment: I'm sorry, but that's well beyond the scope of a simple comment section here. I'd suggest that you continue to Google for some tutorials and examples. Then come back to SO with specific questions on anything that's still not clear for you.